# batch file appearing as visual studio documents

Tags: java

I am trying to download batch files on MacBook but once the download completes the files  automatically defaulti to visual studio code documents. How do I stop the conversion from happening?

Comment: The question is off topic here (and in particular has nothing to do with java). You'll probably want to ask this on [AskDifferent](https://apple.stackexchange.com/), the StackExchange for Apple products.

Comment: Look into changing the File Association for that particular file name extension in your MacBook.